# Yarn install trigger all scripts in my package.json, it is normal?

Tags: yarnpkg

[The documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/) doesn't mention this specifity:

> yarn install is used to install all dependencies for a project. This
>   is most commonly used when you have just checked out code for a
>   project, or when another developer on the project has added a new
>   dependency that you need to pick up.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn install : Install all the dependencies listed within package.json in the local node_modules folder.

Comment: Yeup so it's anormal that it trigger my scripts, even if I'm with workspace I assume.